# Separate download of Photos App for Yosemite

Tags: macos, photos.app

I accidentally deleted the Yosemite's Photos App from my Applications folder but I can't seem to find a separate download link anywhere.

It can't possibly be that I have to re-install Yosemite just to get the app, can it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Time Machine, just restore the app (and its data, if applicable) from an older backup. If not, reinstalling OS X is probably the best idea, as Photos is not available on the Mac App Store and I ***definitely*** wouldn't try to download it elsewhere (so **don't** just type "Mac Photos.app installer" in Bing or Yahoo or Dutch and download whatever comes up). You could copy the app over from a friend or family member, though, if you wish.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) That's what I thought.  I'm not really sure why Apple would prevent people from downloading the Photos app from the App store if you already have Yosemite installed, but nonetheless.

Comment: @dkugappi You're welcome. I'd imagine that Apple doesn't have it available on the App Store because it's a system application and it makes pushing updates to them easier for Apple. By the way, if my answer solved your question, please click the check mark under the arrows to accept the answer.

Comment: Sorry about that added a check mark.